# template condition is not matching

Tags: xslt

I've the below XML.

```
<para><content-style font-style="bold">59/App/1/1 Amendment—</content-style>Para. 
      1(2) of Appendix 1 to Order 59 was amended w.e.f. September 15, 2010 by the
      Rules of Court (Amendment No. 3) Rules 2010 (S 504/2010).
</para>
```

and I've written a dummy XSLT to check for a condition, and [here](http://xsltransform.net/94hvTyL) is the demo, though I've written the condition, and as per the condition the output should be `Hi` where as i'm getting `Hello`.

Please et me know where am i going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-contains, it says about the `contains` function: "If the value of $arg2 is the zero-length string, then the function returns true.".

You could however check

```
<xsl:when test="contains(./content-style[1],'/') and not(matches(substring-before(./content-style[1],'/'),' ')) and not(./@align)">
```

Comment: here I want to print/show `Hi`, as i'm checking if there is no space before `/`, and there is `/` and the para tag doesn't have align

Comment: @user2423959, I think the result with `contains` is by definition when you pass in an empty string, you could however use `matches`, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath expression which is used to select `Hi` or `Hello` in your code will evaluate to false:

```
not(contains(substring-before(/para/content-style[1],'/'),''))
```

because before the first `/` in `content-style` there is `59` not `''`.

Comment: Yes this is what i was searching for, there must be no space before `/`, and there is no but the `otherwise` condition is triggered.